# Compressing bitchains

Tags: combinatorics, information-theory, compression

Let there be a bit-chain consisting of $n$ characters with the following rules:

The probabilities of the first character being  $0$ and $1$ are $1/2$. 
From then on the probabilities are $p$ when the next bit is different and $1-p$ when the next bit is the same, i.e. $P(0_{n+1} |0_{n})=1-p$.

Find the entropy  $H_n$ and find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} H_n$

Comment: Try to post your thoughts about the problem, try to convince us that you want help, and not someone that does your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

Let the bit stream on $n$ characters be $(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)$

Recall the chain rule:

$$H_n:= H(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n) = H(X_1) + H(X_2|X_1) + \dots + H(X_n|X_{n-1}, \dots, X_2, X_1)$$

Note that $\{X_i\}_{n\ge i\ge 1}$ is a Markov process. Consequently, $$H(X_i| X_{i-1}, \dots, X_1) = H(X_i|X_{i-1})$$

Lastly, it's easy to show by induction that $P(X_i = 0) = P(X_i = 1) = 1/2$.

Now, for every $i$,

\begin{align}
H(X_i|X_{i-1}) &= \frac{1}{2} H(X_i|X_{i-1} = 0) + \frac{1}{2} H(X_i|X_{i-1} = 1)\\
&= 2 \times \frac{1}{2}h_2(p) = h_2(p)
\end{align}

and $H(X_1) = 1$.

Putting it all together,

$$H(X_1^n) = 1 + (n-1)h_2(p).$$ The limit as $n \to \infty $ is easy to calculate.